# Python equivalent of select case (CDec(variable)

Tags: python, if-statement, select-case

I'm working on fixing some code in a git project, and have an issue. The program uses key-value pairs, where the value is numeric (as a String). I know how to code it in Visual Basic (or think I do), but I'm not sure how to do it in Python. If I have to convert it and compare that, I can, but I'm trying to minimize the code required.

The VB equivalent of what I want to do is either:

```
select case (CDec(data['Frequency']) >= 144.000 AND CDec(data['Frequency'] <= 174.000)
```

or

```
if (CDec(data['Frequency']) >= 144.000 or CDec(data['Frequency'] <= 174.000) then
```

How would I do this in Python? As I said, I can convert the value to a decimal and compare it, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Thanks, and have a great night. :)
Patrick.

Answer (score 0):

`144.0 <= int(data['Frequency']) <= 174.0`

I guess ... its called chained comparison

and `int` to cast something to int ... (I assume thats what `CDec` does)

Answer (score 0):

CDec() would be the conversion to compare to 144.0 and in Python it is float().

You certainly could use:

if 144.0 <= float(data['Frequency']) <= 178.0 :
   ...